# under pitched (1st) yeast-aerate into fermenter on 2nd (new) pitch or no?

Tags: fermentation, yeast, secondary-fermentation, pitch

I brewed an all grain stout 2 weeks ago, OG was 1.087 which was almost spot on for where I'd hoped.  However, I mis-calculated the pitch rate for my starter.  Racked to secondary to dry hop with mint (it's a chocolate mint stout) and I'm about 10-15 points higher than I need to be on it.  I made another starter yesterday that's on the stir plate ready to pitch.

My question is should I try to aerate the starter somehow on the way in, i.e. over a strainer or will aeration raise potential for infection even more?  I'm currently sitting just under 7%.

Answer (score 2):

If the starter was on the stir plate it is aerated already.  You will however, be introducing oxidized wort from the starter into the beer.  This could be an issue for flavor later on, but it being a big beer with rich flavors it might not be noticeable.

Comment: that's what I was hoping, and also crossing fingers about re-introducing oxygen :(  we'll see what additional points I get out of the FG, thanks for the input!